# How to Compare comparing elements in an arraylist in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, compare, comparison

I have an Arraylist of Soccer teams

```
List<String> teams= new ArrayList<String>(teamCount);     
teams.add("chelsea");     
teams.add("Manchester Utd");     
teams.add("Mancity");     
teams.add("Swanser");     
teams.add("asernal");    
teams.add("aston villa");      
teams.add("bacerlona");     
teams.add("realmadrid");      
List<String>Group1= teams.subList(0,4);     
List<String>Group2= teams.subList(4,8);
```

I need to do the comparision like :
A comparison is done in each Arraylist, so that each team has to play every team in his own group.
 Like for example:

```
Group1
 Chelsea vs Manchester Utd
 Mancity vs Swanser
 Chelsea vs Mancity
 Chelsea vs Swanser
 Mancity vs Manchester Utd
 Manchester Utd vs Swanser



and Group 2
 Asernal vs Aston villa
 Bacerlona vs Aston villa
 Realmadrid vs Aston villa
 Realmadrid vs Bacerlona
 Realmadrid vs Asernal
 Asernal vs Bacerlona
```

Can any one help me.

Comment: Why do you need to compare anything?

Comment: Show us you "comparing" code you've done. You've must tried it first to some extent, then we will try to help.

Comment: Comparing means checking which of two things is greater. For example, is 3 greater than 2 or is "ABC" greater than "DEF". What exactly are you comparing and how do you define "greater than" or "less than" in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea. (I hope em not getting the question wrong)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class p {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Group1 consists of 4 teams, A,B,C and D
    List<String>Group1= new ArrayList<String>() ; 
    Group1.add("A");
    Group1.add("B");
    Group1.add("C");
    Group1.add("D");
    // matches stores the names of the teams which have been selected for a match
    List<String>matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String team1: Group1) {
      for(String team2: Group1) {
        if(!team1.equals(team2) && !matches.contains(team1+team2) && !matches.contains(team2+team1)) {
          matches.add(team1+team2);
          System.out.println(team1 + " vs " + team2); 
        }
      }
    }
    }
}
```

You can use the same approach to get matches for Group2.

Comment: This answer is not helping the OP at all. Did he do any thinking before posting? What was the result of his thinking? What is he struggling on? These are much more important than any piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is an approach for a *combination* of array elements.

So, with four teams (t0, t1, t2, t3) in a group, the combination would be

- t0 - t1
- t0 - t2
- t0 - t3
- t1 - t2
- t1 - t3
- t2 - t3

With this list of resulting combinations you should be able to write the necessary loops.